# unable to run my python file in Powershell

Tags: python-3.x

I'm running my project on PowerShell but every time I run my python file it's give me module not found error.

For eg.

```
   > translate.py
```

from translate import Translator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'translate'

But works fine in pycharm.

I'm expecting to run file in PowerShell. but don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using virtual environment in pycharm. If you don't know use `ls` to see if you have `venv` or `virtualenv` directory in your project folder.
If so you have to run powershell **as an administrator** execute:

```
set-executionpolicy RemoteSigned
```

Then confirmed option with **Y**

Then you need to go to `venv` or `virtualenv` folder to `Scripts` or `bin` subfolder and run:

```
./activate.ps1
cd ../..
```

After that your project should work normally with:

```
python your_file.py
```